# Non constant expression error in unpivot values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g. I have following table (this is just the sample, in reality there are many more records):

```
CREATE TABLE table1(city varchar2(20), state varchar2(20), year varchar2(20), jan integer, feb integer, mar integer);
insert into table1 values('city1','state1','2017',1,2,3);
insert into table1 values('city9','state9','2018',11,12,13);
```

I want to unpivot it to following shape:

```
CITY    STATE   ID_TIMESPAN     USD
city1   state1  2017-01         1
city1   state1  2017-02         2
city1   state1  2017-03         3
city9   state9  2018-01         11
city9   state9  2018-02         12
city9   state9  2018-03         13
```

I get this error when I try the below mentioned code:

> ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values

Here is the code I am trying:

```
select *
from table1
unpivot
(
    USD
    for ID_TIMESPAN in 
    (
        jan as year || '-01',
        feb as year || '-02',
        mar as year || '-03'        
    )
);
```

Please advise how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using inline view.

```
select p2.city, p2.state, p2.year || '-' || p2.ID_months as ID_TIMESPAN, p2.USD
from 
(
    select * from table1
        unpivot
        (
            USD
            for ID_MONTHS in 
            (
                jan as '01',
                feb as '02',
                mar as '03'
            )
        ) 
) p2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table design looks sub-optimal. You shouldn't be having name of the month as column names.

The approach you came up with to get the result is simple and looks good. However, as a side note, if you want to avoid hardcoding months, you may also use :

```
SELECT city
    ,STATE
    ,to_char(to_date(year || ID_TIMESPAN,'YYYYMON'),'YYYY-MM') AS ID_TIMESPAN
    ,usd
FROM Table1
unpivot(USD FOR ID_TIMESPAN IN (
            jan
            ,feb
            ,mar
            ));
```

Comment: Regarding your comment that design looks horrible. I just wanted to reproduce the issue in simple terms. This is not how it is in reality.

Comment: No problem mate, I changed my lines. And reality..it better not be more horrible than this, I hope, that's all :-}